# appending data from another select statment into existing table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am taking data from this select statement

```
SELECT 'NONSTK' AS [FormType]
       ,S.[NonStockCode] AS [KeyField]
       ,'EBQ001' AS [FieldName]
       ,NULL AS [AlphaValue]
       ,1 AS [NumericValue]
       ,NULL AS [DateValue]
    FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[QotNonStock] S
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[AdmFormData] N
        ON S.[NonStockCode] = N.[KeyField]
    WHERE ( N.[FormType] = 'NONSTK'
            OR N.[FormType] IS NULL
          )
        AND N.[KeyField] IS NULL
```

and trying to insert it as the following

```
INSERT INTO [SysproCompanyT].[dbo].[AdmFormData]
        ( [FormType]
        ,[KeyField]
        ,[FieldName]
        ,[AlphaValue]
        ,[NumericValue]
        ,[DateValue]
        )
        SELECT 'NONSTK' AS [FormType]
               ,S.[NonStockCode] AS [KeyField]
               ,'EBQ001' AS [FieldName]
               ,NULL AS [AlphaValue]
               ,1 AS [NumericValue]
               ,NULL AS [DateValue]
            FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[QotNonStock] S
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[AdmFormData] N
                ON S.[NonStockCode] = N.[KeyField]
            WHERE ( N.[FormType] = 'NONSTK'
                    OR N.[FormType] IS NULL
                  )
                AND N.[KeyField] IS NULL
```

Which returns the following

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I had thought I had done this before, but I can not get anywhere near it.

So can it be done?, in the meantime I will start my usp cursor to do a single insert at a time

Comment: What results are returned if you simply do the `SELECT` portion of that statement? Also what table is this "`WHERE ( [FormType] = 'NONSTK' OR [FormType] IS NULL`"Coming From?

Comment: Based on your last statement in question there is extra code that you have that is causing the error and not the code that you have put here. Update your question and add **Entire** code block.

Comment: Are [QotNonStock] and [AdmFormData] views by any chance?

Comment: @Zane Sorry The where statement is from table N (I shall amend in a second) The select statement does as expected and returns all the data that exists in table S where it does not existing table N

Comment: @VladimirOselsky sorry I did not mean to confuse. The is no extra code the usp is the next step

Comment: @Zane sorry to ask but how do I update my original question to include the correct where statement, I can not see it in the help section

Comment: There is an edit button on the question page.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I don't think that edit is coming...

Comment: @VladimirOselsky and Zane Hi sorry I thought I had made the edit to the where statement now shows where FormType comes from 'code'   WHERE ( N.[FormType] = 'NONSTK'
                    OR N.[FormType] IS NULL
                  )
                AND N.[KeyField] IS NULL 'code

Comment: Even with update I see nothing wrong with your query. Are any of the tables in this statement are views?

Comment: No all are tables - I have done a forward cursor to get round the problem but would have liked to understand what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

All

Please see comments above. However to get around my problem I used a forward cursor like this

```
    --This cusor reads from one select statement result set
--loads data from result set in variable on a loop basis
-- and inserts into the existing sql table
-- Declare variable to hold insert data
--REMEMBER THE SEMICOLONS!!!

DECLARE @NonStockCode varchar(80);

--Declare cusor
DECLARE InsertCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
For

    SELECT S.[NonStockCode]
  FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[QotNonStock] S
  left outer join   [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[AdmFormData] N On S.[NonStockCode]=N.[KeyField]
  where (N.[FormType]='NONSTK' or N.[FormType] is null)
  and N.[FieldName] <>'MOU001';

--Open Cusor
OPEN InsertCursor;

--Read first row of data and store in variables
FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor INTO @NonStockCode;
Print @NonStockCode; --Test print

--Now use loop to process result set of cusor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Print 'NONSTK'+' ' +@NonStockCode+'MOU001'; --Test print
        INSERT INTO [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].[AdmFormData]
           ([FormType] ,[KeyField],[FieldName],[AlphaValue],[NumericValue] ,[DateValue])
        VALUES ('NONSTK',@NonStockCode,'MOU001' ,'99',null ,null );
        FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor INTO  @NonStockCode;
    END
--Now Close and deallocate the cursor MUST HAPPEN
CLOSE InsertCursor;
DEALLOCATE InsertCursor;
Go
```